# Docker: Route Traffic from One Container to Another Container Through a VPN Container

Tags: docker, networking, containers

I set up an SSTP client container (172.17.0.3) that communicates with an SSTP server container (172.17.0.2) via the `ppp0` interface. All traffic from the SSTP client container is routed through its `ppp0` interface, as seen using `netstat` on the SSTP client container (192.168.20.1 is the SSTP server container's `ppp0` IP address):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.20.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.20.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
```

Now, I have an HTTP server container (172.17.0.4) running, and I want to use yet another client container (for example, a container that runs Apache Benchmark `ab`) to talk to the HTTP server container via the SSTP server container. To do so, I use `--net=container:sstp-client` on the `ab` client container so it uses the SSTP client container's network. However, the `ab` client container cannot seem to reach the HTTP server container, even though *it is able to benchmark servers on the Internet (e.g., 8.8.8.8)*. For another example, if I do `traceroute` from a container through the SSTP client container to `8.8.8.8`:

```
 docker run -it --name alpine --net=container:sstp-client alpine ash
/ # traceroute -s 192.168.20.2 google.com
traceroute to google.com (142.250.65.206) from 192.168.20.2, 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  192.168.20.1 (192.168.20.1)  1.088 ms  1.006 ms  1.077 ms
 2  *  *  *
 3  10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2)  1.710 ms  1.695 ms  0.977 ms
 4  *  *  *
...
```

I am able to finally reach Google.
But if I `traceroute` to my HTTP server container:

```
/ # traceroute -s 192.168.20.2 172.17.0.4
traceroute to 172.17.0.4 (172.17.0.4) from 192.168.20.2, 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  *  *  *
 2  *  *  *
 3  *  *  *
 4  *  *  *
 5  *  *  *
...
```

It fails.

My suspicion is that the routing configuration on the SSTP server container is incorrect, but I am not sure how I can fix that to make it work. My goal is to be able to reach both the outside world and the internal containers. I've messed around with both `iptables` and `route` quite a bit, but still can't make it work. This is my current configuration of the SSTP server container:

```
/ # netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.20.0    172.17.0.2      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
192.168.20.0    172.17.0.2      255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.20.2    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
/ # iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
```

I've seen many online solutions on how to route via a VPN container to the Internet, but nothing about to another containers. Very much a newbie in this area. Any suggestions welcome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to choose similar approach to this problem. Nevertheless I have it inside gitlab-ci...

Start VPN container and find its IP

```
docker run -it -d --rm \
  --name vpn-client-${SOME_VARIABLE} \
  --privileged \
  --net gitlab-runners \
  -e VPNADDR=... \
  -e VPNUSER=... \
  -e VPNPASS=... \
  auchandirect/forticlient || true && sleep 2

export VPN_CONTAINER_IP=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' vpn-client-${SOME_VARIABLE})
```

Next you have to add new variable into your application container and add new ROUTE, eg docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  test-server:
    image: alpine
    variables:
      ROUTE_IP: "${VPN_CONTAINER_IP}"
    command: "ip route add <CIDR_TARGET_SUBNET> via ${ROUTE_IP}"
networks:
  default:
    name: gitlab-runners
    external: true
```

But be advised IP mentioned above HAS to be in CIDR format (eg 192.168.1.0/24) and also be in SAME docker network